# Who was Hogwart? What is known about the family?

Tags: harry-potter

Who was Hogwart and what happened to the Hogwart family?
Are or were any of them wizards?
What else is known? Presumably there are portraits of the family as in any castle. Are any of these seen?

Comment: BEST HARRY POTTER QUESTION EVAR!

Comment: It wasn't a family name, it appeared to Rowena Ravenclaw in a vision of warty hogs...

Comment: @Richard Goddammit, I was 2 seconds from submitting an answer when the hammer came down! :-[

Comment: What makes you think there was ever a person named "Hogwart"? The castle wasn't [built by anyone with that name](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Architect_of_Hogwarts). There's also an [out of universe explanation](http://www.languagerealm.com/hplang/hogwarts.php) for the name.

Comment: There's no such family.  As explained by the Sorting Hat, Hogwarts was founded over a thousand year ago by four great wizards: Rowena Ravenclaw, Salazar Slytherin, Helga Hufflepuff and Godric Gryffindor.  As for the name of the school, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72903/4918 Was Hogwarts named such because of a connection to warthogs? explains that “The location and name of Hogwarts were both chosen by Rowena Ravenclaw, who dreamed that a warty hog was leading her to the cliff by the lake.”

Comment: @b_jonas - [Sorry](http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/156417/file-67428897-jpeg/images/thor-hammer-time-resized-600.jpeg)

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/103657/4918 Why are there no portraits of the founders of school in Hogwarts?

Comment: So was the castle built purely to be a school? Or, putting it another way, was it a castle when it was built or did it grow into a castle over time?

Comment: "It's _Hoggle_!"